# data contention with objects Kubernetes Pods

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

I have 4 pods (A, B, C, D) running instances of the same object that are causing failures.  Here is something like the type of issue we're experiencing:

instance in Pod A --> Reads file name myfile_1 from db, transfers the file, then deletes file from directory then updates the db with status of "sent"
instance in Pod B --> Reads same file name myfile_1 from db before status is updated to sent, tries to transfer the same file, and errors out because instance in Pod A already sent the file and deleted it.

Same issue could happen with instances C & D.....

We've already tried updating the status first, that lessens the problem, but does not eliminate it, because the two instances could be attempting the same action close to the same time.

Is there something similar to the synchronize function in Java that could be used with objects in Pods that would block instance in Pod B from operating on the same data as instance in POD A, until instance in POD A is done.

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Redis could help here.

Comment: This also sounds like a place a job queue like RabbitMQ might be a good match.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical distributed transaction problem that is not really related to Kubernetes. You can solve this by introducing more states, and making sure you're running with the right transaction isolation level at the db. Three status values, "ready", "sending", and "sent" should work. Each pod polls the db for status "ready", and picks one and changes that to "sending". Once done, it changes "sending" to "sent".

The important point is that the status DB update must be atomic, by using a clause that amounts to "set status=sending where status=ready" in whatever db you're using.

There are other solutions using a central transaction controller, but the db solution works without introducing additional complexity.

Comment: The problem is that 2 instances can pickup the same record for processing within milliseconds of each other, before either one of them has had a chance to update the status.

Comment: If you use the correct transaction isolation level and update the status as I described, that will not happen

Comment: It's possible that both instances will start working on the same record, and both try to update the database, but only one of them will succeed; the other will get an error running the specific update described in this answer.